# Modern French prose/fiction authors to read/listen for French language learner

Tags: apprentissage

I am looking for list/or just some recommendations on modern French fiction books/writers for French language learners. Modern because I want to see plain and modern language close to real spoken language of today. Fiction because I want gripping narrative/easy story flow so that I wish make it to the end and repeat more than once. I prefer to try and find something in audio book format for my learning - but to begin with I just want to see recommendation of books/authors. I'm somewhere between A2/B1 levels but I do not want any simplified/adopted for learners book.

Comment: what do you mean by "for French language learners" ?  regular book with easy vocabulary, like, for teenagers ? something else ?  And what would be the list of requirement ? (length, rude langage, etc). Beside, I've no idea what A2/B1 level is.

Comment: No I'm adult language learner and I do want original books (not adjusted for learners) to complement my learning. I just indicated my level to give an idea that plain language will be useful for me, but I'm ready listen "real" language till I be able to understand it. For A2/B1 refer to CEFR - Common European Framework of Reference for Languages and its Common reference levels, there is good Wikipedia article on this.

Answer (score 3):

Why not Maxime Chattam books ? :)

Comment: Thanks for recommendation, I will give it a try, though I would prefer something a bit more realistic maybe instead of Steven King type of fiction :) But I need to give it try before giving any further opinions